Radiance Theorem
Radiance theorem expresses conservation of radiance between a source and a detector, but it is confusing to me. Usually the standard proof of this theorem starts like this:
Consider two area elements $dA_o$ and $dA_1$ separated by a distance $r$ and define the following two solid angles:
$$w_0 = \frac{dA_1\cos(a_1)}{r^2} ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ 
w_1 = \frac{dA_o\cos(a_0)}{r^2} , $$
where $a_0$ is the angle between the normal of the element $dA_o$ of the source surface and the direction of the solid angle $w_o$ and $a_1$ is the angle between the normal of the element $dA_1$ of the detector surface and the direction of the solid angle $w_1$. $w_0$ is the solid angle subtended by $dA_1$ in $dA_o$ and $w_1$ is the angle subtended by $dA_o$ in $dA_1$. Then the proof follows from the definition of radiance. If we call $L_o$ the radiance at the source and $L_1$ the radiance at the detector, then by definition of radiance:
The radiant flux is
$$d^2f =L_o(dA_o\cos(a_o))dw_o =L_1(dA_1\cos(a_1)dw_1) , $$
and after substituting the expressions for $w_o$ and $w_1$ we get the result $L_o = L_1$.
I'm struggling to understand this theorem. Is the radiance conserved globally or only between  a certain couple of points? What do all these differentials mean? What if I have an extended source and an extended detector? Differentials are really confusing to me , can this proof be explained without using them?
